# NaN countdown timer javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have created a javascript countdown for a wordpress custom plugin. I've read [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/) and this is the first time I try to make something similar. After I've ended writing the code I was testing it and initially it was working fine. Now if I try to log the values of the hours minutes days and seconds in console I get a `NaN` message. I don't know what's wrong, can anyone help me?

```
<?php if( get_option('show-countdown') ): ?>
                    <div class="countdown">
                        <h1 class="days d-inline"></h1>
                        <h1 class="hours d-inline"></h1>
                        <h1 class="minutes d-inline"></h1>
                        <h1 class="seconds d-inline"></h1>
                    </div>

                    <script>
                    (function($){
                      $(document).ready(function(){

                            var date = '<?php echo get_option('countdown-timer'); ?>';
                            console.log(date);
                            function remainingTime( date ){
                                var countdown = Date.parse(date) - Date.parse(new Date());
                                var seconds = Math.floor( (countdown/1000) % 60 );
                                var minutes = Math.floor( (countdown/1000/60) % 60 );
                                var hours = Math.floor( (countdown/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
                                var days = Math.floor( countdown/(1000*60*60*24) );
                                return {
                                'total': countdown,
                                'd': days,
                                'h': hours,
                                'm': minutes,
                                's': seconds
                              };
                            }

                            console.log(remainingTime(date));

                            function initClock( endtime ){
                                var timeinterval = setInterval(function(){
                                    var t = remainingTime( endtime );

                                    $('.days').html(t.d);
                                    $('.hours').html(t.h);
                                    $('.minutes').html(t.m);
                                    $('.seconds').html(t.s);
                                }, 1000);
                            }
                            initClock( '.countdown', date );

                        });
                    }(jQuery));
                    </script>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: does `console.log(date);` correctly output the date you passed via PHP?

Comment: also, you are calling `initClock` function passing it 2 parameters, while your function declaration seems to accept only 1 parameter (`endtime`)

Comment: consider this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yk7m8zu1/ it logs numbers. `Object
total: -65895000
d: -1
h: -19
m: -19
s: -15
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that you were passing two arguments to `initClock`, but the method signature only accepted one (`endTime`). By removing the first argument, which appeared to be an unused CSS selector string, the problem is resolved:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var date = '2030-01-01';
    console.log(date);

    function remainingTime(date) {
      var countdown = Date.parse(date) - Date.parse(new Date());
      var seconds = Math.floor((countdown / 1000) % 60);
      var minutes = Math.floor((countdown / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      var hours = Math.floor((countdown / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      var days = Math.floor(countdown / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      return {
        'total': countdown,
        'd': days,
        'h': hours,
        'm': minutes,
        's': seconds
      };
    }

    console.log(remainingTime(date));

    function initClock(endtime) {
      var timeinterval = setInterval(function() {
        var t = remainingTime(endtime);

        $('.days').html(t.d);
        $('.hours').html(t.h);
        $('.minutes').html(t.m);
        $('.seconds').html(t.s);
      }, 1000);
    }
    
    initClock(date);
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="countdown">
  <h1 class="days d-inline"></h1>
  <h1 class="hours d-inline"></h1>
  <h1 class="minutes d-inline"></h1>
  <h1 class="seconds d-inline"></h1>
</div>
```

Note: since this was primarily about the JavaScript, I removed the PHP conditional and hardcoded a date value in place of the `get_option` call.

Comment: I'm using the hardcoded `get_option()` function of wordpress because I'm not able to use the `wp_localize_script()` to pass the needed value from the backend. This because the plugin script is using the `wp_loaded` hook to show the maintenance screen page so the `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` functions are not fired and I'm not able to pass the data.

Comment: @sisaln Sure, you're welcome to continue to do that, I just noted that I changed it for the example to run so you didn't get confused.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have also a solution to use the `wp_enqueue_` functions when it's used the `wp_loaded` hook action?